# Función Activada Cuando Aparece Una Determinada Clase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hola quisiera que la función relativa a la clase "outtime" se activase tras aparecer el div; de tal forma que el div desaparezca un segundo después de aparecer (en este caso)

```js
$(function() {
    $("[class*=outtime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/outtime\d+/g)[0].replace("outtime",""));
        setInterval("$('.outtime" + retraso + "').fadeOut(0)", retraso * 1000);
    });
});


$(function() {
    $("[class*=intime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/intime\d+/g)[0].replace("intime",""));
        $(this).delay(retraso * 1000).fadeIn(0);
    });
});
```

```css
.cuadrado{ height:100px;width:100px; background:red;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cuadrado intime2 outtime1">
</div>
```

Comment: Al final te vamos a acabar haciendo el proyecto completo nosotros :P

Comment: Tienes razón, se me ha ido, intentaré resolverlo solo y publicaré la respuesta ! @alvaromontoro

Comment: No me refiero a eso. Iba a publicar una respuesta, pero no sé si es exactamente lo que buscas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución sería añadir el outtime justo después del intime. Para ello, dentro de la función del intime:

- Lee el retraso a aplicar al intime
- Lee el retraso a aplicar al outtime
- Encadena el outtime cuando apliques el outtime

El código se vería así:

```js
$(function() {
    $("[class*=outtime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/outtime\d+/g)[0].replace("outtime",""));
        setInterval("$('.outtime" + retraso + "').fadeOut(0)", retraso * 1000);
    });
});


$(function() {
    $("[class*=intime]").each(function() {
        var retrasointime  = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/intime\d+/g)[0].replace("intime",""));
        var retrasoouttime = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/outtime\d+/g)[0].replace("outtime",""));
        $(this).delay(retrasointime * 1000).fadeIn(0).delay(retrasoouttime * 1000).fadeOut(0);
    });
});
```

```css
.cuadrado{ height:100px;width:100px; background:red;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cuadrado intime2 outtime1">
</div>
```

Alternativamente, para evitar problemas con el outtime ocultando el intime en el momento inadecuado (porque outtime se ejecuta en intervalos), quizás podrías aplicarlo de manera diferente:

```
$("[class*=outtime]").not("[class*=intime]").each(function() {
```

De este modo, sólo se aplica cuando el elemento tiene clase outtime pero no intime.

Comment: Joder @alvaromontoro algún día te invitaré a una copa

Comment: Lo que intento es que desaparezca 2 segundos después de aparecer el div, ahora mismo lo tengo para 1 segundo después y no aparece sin embargo si pongo para 3 segundos después aparece a los 2 segundos y desaparece al segundo siguiente. Por eso supuse que tenía que conseguir una función que se disparase cuando aparece el elemento para poder hacerlo del modo que quiero.

Comment: He corregido un fallo en el código. Para evitar el problema que mencionas en el comentario, te recomiendo que hagas lo que aparece en el último párrafo de la respuesta (detrás del ejemplo)

Comment: Hey, muchísimas gracias!